# Laravel Telescope hide Nova requests

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-nova

How can I disable Telescope for all Nova related things? With some clicks in Nova, my whole Telescope is full of their requests. I don't care about Nova-requests, but can't figure out how to disable registering those requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look at the telescope documentation there is a gate watcher that seems to exclude a viewNova gate as an example, maybe that would help clear some of the queries.

> The gate watcher records the data and result of gate and policy checks
>   by your application. If you would like to exclude certain abilities
>   from being recorded by the watcher, you may specify those in the
>   ignore_abilities option in your config/telescope.php file:

```
'watchers' => [
    Watchers\GateWatcher::class => [
        'enabled' => env('TELESCOPE_GATE_WATCHER', true),
        'ignore_abilities' => ['viewNova'],
    ],
    ...
],
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/telescope#gate-watcher